# Verilog code to calculate number of rows and columns from an input image frame

Tags: image-processing, verilog

I am having troubles with a verilog module which is a small part of a very big CMOS camera image code.The module takes in clk and reset as inputs and spits out hsync,vsync,pixclk and pixel data.The code reads in an image and saves it to memory and then does a a bunch of if else statements like :

```
if (row_count<NUM_ROWS-1) && (col_count< NUM_COLS) 
begin 
 vsync <=1; 
 hsync <=1 ;
 pixe_data <= mem[row_count*NUM_ROWS+col_count];
end
else if
 ......
```

Till now the image dimensions were hard coded using NUM_COLS and NUM_ROWS but I am trying to change this such that the code counts the rows and columns of the incoming image on the fly. I have tried using $fscanf,$fgets,$Sscanf etc but I am not getting the right results.In fact I am getting no results at all.My simulation gets stuck or it says its out of memory or fd is a null file descriptor.Also when I convert NUM_ROWS and NUM_COLS to be variables I get an error saying illegal operand for constant operation.

I would much appreciate if some could give me some insight into a different method to approach this problem.

My apologies in advance if the information here is insufficient or unclear.

Thanks
SK

Comment: I assume using file utilities is only for testbench purposes and that the DUT (main module) is going to be given an x and y resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The illegal operand for constraint operations is likely due to the dimension for `mem`. The dimensions needs to be a constant, e.g. `reg [DATA_SIZE-1:0] mem [ROW_MAX*COL_MAX-1:0];` You'll need to decide the max image size you will process. If the max dimensions are not `2**N` then you will need to implement some from of protection, e.g. signal an error and not process anything, truncate the image, or something else.

I'm not sure how to find the rows and columns of unknown image dimensions without writing custom a PLI. `$fscanf` can read in the image data and you will most likely want to use `"%u"` for format component. If image contains information about its dimentions in the file itself, then you could extract information with the `$fscanf` or `$fread`.

---

Other note, from your original code snip-it:

```
pixe_data <= mem[row_count*NUM_ROWS+col_count];
```

should be:

```
pixe_data <= mem[row_count*NUM_COLS+col_count];
```

Otherwise there is a risk of accessing the same data from different addresses or something out of range.